# Biasing of a circuit

Tags: circuit-design, biasing

Biasing circuits are designed to fix the Q – point at the centre of the active region. why it is designed in this way?

Comment: ... Because that's where it has the most active region to swing through...

Comment: Only if you're talking about class A biasing - there are others http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/amplifier/amplifier-classes.html

Answer (score 0):

Biasing is actually more complicated. It also depends on the device in question, and the desired performance. Depending on the biasing point we can also influence noise performance, distortion, ...

However, often we bias in the middle to give us the most available signal swing.